# Using different data types in EagerTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

Using the *Tensorflow 2.0 alpha*, I received the error `ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor`, when I was trying to create a `tf.data.Dataset` using the following data:

[image]

*[Inspect the complete dataset on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)*

Obviously, there are mixed data types. `Sex` is a string, `Age` a float/double, `SibSp` and `Parch` are Integers and so on.

My (Python 3) code to transform this *Pandas Dataframe* into a `tf.data.Dataset` is based on Tensorflow's tutorial on [How to classify structured data](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/keras/feature_columns), and looks like the following:

```
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()

  # the 'Survived' column is the label (not shown in the image of the Dataframe but exists in the Dataframe)
  label = dataframe.pop('Survived')

  # create the dataset from the dataframe
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), label))

  # if shuffle == true, randomize the entries
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)

  return ds
```

As already mentioned above, this function will throw the error **`ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor`** when executing it with, for instance:

```
train_ds = df_to_dataset(df_train, batch_size=32)
```

(while `df_train` is the pandas dataframe you can see in the image)

Now I wonder if I am missing something because Tensorflow's tutorial (mentioned above) is using a dataframe with mixed types, as well, but I ran into no errors when trying this example with exactly the same `df_to_dataset` function.

Comment: Function itself will work, but you missed feature_layer, which defines feature columns in your code.

Comment: @Sharky But feature columns are defined after calling this function aren't they? If so, they wouldn't have any impact on the result of this function. Because the error already occurs when calling `df_to_dataset` and not e.g. when training the model

Comment: Strangely, I'm not getting any errors when simply iterating over dataset

Comment: @Sharky What do you mean by iterating over the dataset?

Comment: `for i in train_ds:
    print(i)`
where i is a single batch. If you're using TF2.0

Comment: Hmm the problem is that I don't even get to print the `train_ds` because `train_ds` throws an error on creation @Sharky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is due to NaN values is specific columns.
Detect them with `dataframe['Name'].isnull().sum())` and replace.

Comment: Thanks very much! Noticed it accidentally in the exact same moment as you wrote this, when I tried to use `df.astype(str)` on all string columns

Comment: I replaced all columns with missing values using `dataframe = dataframe.dropna()`

Comment: That is one of many options, I guess. I was a bit surprised that NaNs were the issue, datatypes could be tricky sometime